# Distribution of inner product of random unit vectors

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, inner-product

Suppose I have two $2\times2$ Haar random unitary matrices $u_1$ and $u_2$, then I can define a diagonal matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}(u_1\cdot u_2)_{11}&0\\ 0&(u_1\cdot X\cdot u_2)_{11}\end{pmatrix}.$$
Here $X$ is the Pauli matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1& 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Now I want to ask the probability distribution of this diagonal matrix. How to solve it?

It seems that I can view $(u_1\cdot u_2)_{11}$ as the inner product of two random unit vectors. Using the fact that $u_1$ and $u_2$ are chosen Haar randomly, will this problem be solvable?

Comment: I presume with $\ast$ you mean matrix mulitplication?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the unclear notation

Answer (score 1):

Parameterize $u_n\in\text{U}(2)$ by
$$u_n=e^{i\phi_n}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 e^{i (\alpha_n+\alpha'_n)}\cos \theta_n  & - e^{i (\alpha_n-\alpha'_n)}\sin \theta_n \\
  e^{-i (\alpha_n-\alpha'_n)}\sin \theta_n & e^{-i (\alpha_n+\alpha'_n)}\cos \theta_n  \\
\end{array}
\right),$$
with $\alpha_n,\alpha'_n,\phi_n\in(0,2\pi)$ and $\theta_n\in(0,\pi/2)$.
The Haar measure is
$$P(\alpha_n,\alpha'_n,\phi_n,\theta_n)=(2\pi)^{-3}\sin(2\theta_n).$$
The matrix $\Omega$ constructed by the OP has elements
$$\Omega=\begin{pmatrix}
(u_1 u_2)_{11}&0\\
0&(u_1X u_2)_{11}
\end{pmatrix},\;\;\text{with}\;\;X=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0\end{pmatrix}. $$
Its distribution assuming independent $u_1,u_2$ is
$$P(\alpha_1,\alpha'_1,\phi_1,\theta_1,\alpha_2,\alpha'_2,\phi_2,\theta_2)=(2\pi)^{-6}\sin(2\theta_1)\sin(2\theta_2).$$

A few phases may be eliminated,
$$\Omega=\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\
0&b\end{pmatrix},$$
$$a=e^{i\phi}\cos\theta\cos\theta'-e^{i\phi'-i\phi''}\sin\theta\sin\theta',$$
$$b=e^{i\phi'}\cos\theta\sin\theta'-e^{i\phi-i\phi''}\sin\theta\cos\theta',$$
$$P(\phi,\phi',\phi'',\theta,\theta')=(2\pi)^{-3}\sin(2\theta)\sin(2\theta').$$